# Installation of 19.04 wold not boot after installation

Tags: reboot, 19.04

I have downloaded Ubuntu 19.04 from Ubuntu side.
The installation going well, after that I have rebooted my computer, but the login appear but the code will be not accepted and will com again and again.I clean my hard drive with deb an and install the Ubuntu 19.04 again. It will be the same and now there will not accept my Password by installing new software.
I'm thinking about to change from Ubuntu to Fedora.

Comment: What brand/model system? Did you check install proprietary drivers? What video card/chip? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &

Comment: @oldfred I think it's a login loop, not a boot problem.

Comment: If it's the "live" installation media, I had a similar issue with Ubuntu Server.  The installer booted and ran fine, but then I was greeted with "no bootable media" after it was finished and restarted.  I had to download the full fat "alternate" installer image and use that instead, which worked flawlessly.  It's something about the way those smaller "live" installer discs set up the bootloader,  or rather, how they don't, on older machines.